# Better Way To Plot OHLC Minute Data From Imported csv in R

Tags: r, zoo, quantmod

It took me quite a bit of time to get this to work, but I have plotted an OHLC chart for 1 minute timeframes for AAPL on 2/28/14 using the below function.  The csv file can be downloaded here, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4xAKSwsHiEBRGlyMEE3V0ROckU/edit?usp=sharing

```
PlotAAPLData <- function()
{

  library(zoo)
  library(quantmod)

  z <- read.csv("AAPL 1 min 2-28-14.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
  z <- read.zoo(z, header = TRUE, index = 1:2, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
  z$Volume <- 0
  z$Adjusted <- 0
  z <- as.quantmod.OHLC(z)
  chartSeries(z, type = "bars", theme = chartTheme("white"))
}
```

I had to coerce the data to work with quantmod, however, I don't need any of the functionality that quantmod offers, other than to plot the OHLC, so converting it into that format is not really necessary.

Ia there a better way to do this?  The most challenging part was getting the data into zoo format as the dates have to be just so.  Looking at it now, it doesn't seem so complicated but it was a while in coming.

Thanks.

Comment: The `read.csv` and zero setting are not needed.  `read.zoo` can do it all at once: `z <- read.zoo("AAPL 1 min 2-28-14.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", index = 1:2, tz = "", format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")[, 1:4]`

Comment: Thank you. The import to z works well.  However, when doing as.quantmod, it requires the the volume and adjusted column.  Without it, this error is generated: Error in as.quantmod.OHLC(z) : 'col.names' must match number of columns of 'x'

Comment: After creating `z` using `read.zoo` just run `chartSeries(z)` on that.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you again. I discovered chartSeries as part of quantmod and assumed the data needed to be converted to quantmod in order to be charted.  You have corrected that assumption.